# Set PrimeFaces socket timeout

Tags: sockets, jakarta-ee, primefaces, atmosphere

I am able to use push method using primefaces. How I can control the p:socket timeout events and its time?
I mean, How I can set `p:socket` timeout? Besides, 
How to catch an event when p:socket session is timed out?

I am using following some portion of code statements related to `p:socket`.

**//xhmtl**

```
<p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/chat" autoConnect="false"
    widgetVar="subscriber" />
```

**//Bean**

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("subscriber.connect('/" + usernamePushContext+ "')");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution consisting of two steps.
First, you have to add servlet param in to `web.xml` and implement  `PushContextListener`.

```
    <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.CometSupport.maxInactiveActivity</param-name>
    <param-value>9000</param-value>
```

Second , at each onDisconnect() method invocation you should check transport value.

```
  @Override
   public void onDisconnect(Object arg0) {

String transport = ((AtmosphereRequest) arg0).getRequest().getParameter
(HeaderConfig.X_ATMOSPHERE_TRANSPORT);
```

Based on the transport value, you can trigger disconnection processes.

```
     if (transport != null && 
        (transport.equalsIgnoreCase(HeaderConfig.DISCONNECT) || 
         transport.equalsIgnoreCase(HeaderConfig.LONG_POLLING_TRANSPORT)
     )) {

    // close operation...
     }
```